# How to retrieve logs to investigate dropped database user in SQL Server in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

A database user was unexpectedly removed, I would like to know the details of the operation that caused it. It did not have audit enable at that point.

I tried querying `sys.event_log_ex` without success. What table/view would contain that information?

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [database_name]
      ,[start_time]
      ,[end_time]
      ,[event_category]
      ,[event_type]
      ,[event_subtype]
      ,[event_subtype_desc]
      ,[severity]
      ,[event_count]
      ,[description]
      ,[additional_data]
  FROM [sys].[event_log_ex]
  where [database_name] like 'DbInstance-2338'
```

The user is a "database-contained" user, i.e., its credentials allows connecting to the database only.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my test, it seems the only method to retrieve such info is using audit. If you don't have audit at that moment, i'm afraid it's not possible to find the details anymore.